# How to create RemoteService in pure AS3 application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to make a remote service call from my pure AS3 application.
In the case of Pure AS3 the RemoteObject class is unavailable.
Does any one can help me with a solution.

Thanks,
Sudesh

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class I wrote for this. I use it on every project so I don't have to think about it any more.

```
public class ServiceCaller extends EventDispatcher
{
    private static var s__instance:ServiceCaller;

    private var m__netConnection:NetConnection;

    public function ServiceCaller() 
    {
        var l__tempConnection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        l__tempConnection.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF3;
        m__netConnection = new NetConnection();
        m__netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
        m__netConnection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
        m__netConnection.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);       
    }

    public function connect(i__url:String):void
    {           
        m__netConnection.connect(Model.instance.config.gatewayUrl); 
    }

    private function netStatusHandler(i__event:NetStatusEvent):void 
    {
        trace(i__event.info.code);
    }

    private function statusHandler(i__object:Object):void
    {
        for (var l__key:String in i__object)
            trace(l__key, i__object[l__key]);
        CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
    }

    private function securityErrorHandler(i__event:SecurityErrorEvent):void 
    {
        throw new Error("securityErrorHandler: " + i__event.toString());
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler(i__event:IOErrorEvent):void 
    {
        throw new Error("ioErrorHandler: " + i__event.toString());
    }

    public function callService(i__name:String, i__listener:Function, ...arguments):void
    {
        m__netConnection.call.apply(m__netConnection, [i__name, new Responder(i__listener, statusHandler)].concat(arguments));
    }


    static public function get instance():ServiceCaller 
    {           
        if (!s__instance)
            s__instance = new ServiceCaller();
        return s__instance; 
    }

    static public function set instance(value:ServiceCaller):void 
    {
        s__instance = value;
    }

}
```

To use it, you have first to call once `ServiceCaller.instance.connect("gatewayURL");` and then each time you want a call:

```
ServiceCaller.instance.callService("serviceName", onResult, param1, param2);
```

`onResult` is a callback function taht gets the result as a parameter. You can add as many parameters as your service needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use flash.net.NetConnection ... check the call() method and also the flash.net.Responder class.